# how to render data to select2 using backbone marionette js

Tags: javascript, marionette, jquery-select2

i am using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) i am able to render the sample data but really don't know how to integrate with data from server side.

following is my select box :

```
<select id="fund-code" tabindex="1" style="width:200px;">
                <option value=""><option>
                <option value="1">Mustard</option>
                <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
                <option value="3">Relish</option>
            </select>
```

onShow of the view i do the following :

```
$("#fund-code").select2({
                 placeholder: "Select Fund Code",
                 allowClear: true
             });
```

after this how to put data from server side to this select box??

please suggest me the ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do this :

create model :

```
var FetchMasters = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url : Hexgen.getContextPath("/referencedata/portfolios")
    });
```

append the options like the below :

```
 var fetchMasters = new FetchMasters();

                fetchMasters.fetch({
                    success : function() {
                        for(var masterNum in fetchMasters.attributes) {
                            $("#fund-code").append("<option>" + fetchMasters.attributes[masterNum].portfolio  + "</option>");
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#fund-code").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Fund Code",
                     allowClear: true
                });
```